# How to handle the error "Counter too larger error" in document class "beamer"?

Tags: beamer, numbering

I am creating a presentation in LaTeX using document class"beamer". My presentation contains a large number of figures (more than 26). LaTeX document was compiled properly until no. of figures were less than 26. Later, I started getting the error "Counter too large". I am using the packages "graphixc" and "subfig". I could get the information that the package ***alphalph*** can be used. However, I am not able to use it properly? how can I fix this error so that I can include my all figures in the presentation? Minimal working example (MWE) is attached herewith. Thanking you in anticipation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\alphalphval}[1]{\alphalph{\value{#1}}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{subfloat}{%
    \let\alph\alphalphval%
  }
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[SAR-MS Fusion]{Pre-synopsis Seminar} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author{\small Samadhan C. Kulkarni} % Your name

\institute[College of Engineering, Pune] 
{
College of Engineering, Pune \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.7]
\frametitle{Overview}
\vspace{-6 mm}  % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it
\tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
\end{frame}
\section{Introduction} 
\subsection{Definition}
\begin{frame}
 \graphicspath{{D:/Figures/}}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[Noisy Image]{
%\includegraphics[width=28mm, height=28mm]{H_HV_clip9Nov_noisy.png}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{coep_logo.jpg}
}\hspace{4mm}
\subfloat[Subset]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{coep_logo.jpg}
}\hspace{4mm}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\Huge{\centerline{The End}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code compiles (after I add the document class option 'demo', but it doesn't generate any error or warning messages and hence doesn't help diagnose the situation you're looking to fix. Please tell us more about your (real) document. E.g., how are figures and subfigures numbered? Alphabetically? Do you have more than 26 `figure` environments, or more than 26 subfloats within a `figure`? For that matter, why use `figure` (and `table`) environments at all in a `beamer` document?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you like to number your images with letters and that for this purposes you use `subfig` caption. To extend numbereing over 26 (sub)figures you need only to define `\thesubfig` accordingly:

```
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}}
```

*Off-topic*: document class `beamer` load packages `graphics` and `hyperref`, so you not need to load them again.

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}
\graphicspath{{D:/Figures/}}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{subfig}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title[SAR-MS Fusion]{Pre-synopsis Seminar} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page
\author{\small Samadhan C. Kulkarni} % Your name
\institute[College of Engineering, Pune]
{
College of Engineering, Pune \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Overview}
\tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Definition}

\setcounter{subfigure}{25}  % <--- remove in real document
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
\subfloat[Noisy Image]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{coep_logo.jpg}
}\hfil
\subfloat[Subset]{
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{coep_logo.jpg}
}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\Huge{\centerline{The End}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

After your comment is not entirely clear anymore how you like to have numbered captions. Now I see two possibilities:

- Captions are numbered but without caption label (for example "Figure")

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> 
{
\usetheme{Madrid}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FIGURE STYLE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{(\insertcaptionnumber)\ \insertcaption} % <---
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\footnotesize} % <---
}
\graphicspath{{D:/Figures/}}

\usepackage{booktabs, 
            tabularx} % new
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{gensymb}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title[SAR-MS Fusion]{Pre-synopsis Seminar} 
\author{\small Samadhan C. Kulkarni} % Your name
\institute[College of Engineering, Pune]
{
College of Engineering, Pune \\ 
\medskip
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Overview}
\tableofcontents 
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Definition}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{CC}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{coep_logo.jpg}
\caption{Noisy Image}
    &
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{coep_logo.jpg}
\caption{Subset}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{CC}
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{coep_logo.jpg}
\caption{Whatever}
    &
\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{coep_logo.jpg}
\caption{Figure 4}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which yields to:

[image]

- - Captions with numbered labels. In this case in above MWE you need to replace `\setbeamertemplate{caption}{(\insertcaptionnumber)\ \insertcaption}` with:

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
```

With it the result of compilation is:

[image]

*Note*:

- As you can see in both cases images are inserted in `tabularx` table environment.
- If you still like to have sub figures in some figures, than in above MWE you need to load in preamble the package `subfig` and than use it for example as:

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
\subfloat[Noisy Image]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{coep_logo.jpg}}
   \hfil
\subfloat[Subset]{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{coep_logo.jpg}}
%
\caption{Figure with two sub figures}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to number the image with numbers instead of letters. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @sckulkarni - By "numbers", you mean "arabic numerals", right? If so, do give `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\arabic{subfigure}}` a shot.

Comment: @sckulkarni, do you see addendum to my answer? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @Zarko, my issue was resolved with your first answer. But I wanted to explore it further. Thanks a lot for your addendum.

Comment: @sckulkarni, I'm curious, if my first answer resolve your problem, why you not accept it?